# Programming a game, Code executing is random

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

**Hello All, am just a beginner in C# in VS2010 and the reason am learning it is to be able to evolve in game programming, I got the source code of this program and added many things to it. This is the console application source.**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace First_Game

{
     class Program
    {
        void DisplayChoices(int heroHitPoints, int monsterHitPoints) // 1st method to display the choices 
        {
            Console.Write(@"
************************************************
Your hero has {0}hp and the Monster has {1}hp
************************************************", heroHitPoints, monsterHitPoints);

            Console.Write(@"
__________________________
Please Choose an action:
(A)ttack
(D)efend
(H)eal
(F)lee
__________________________");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        int GetHeroDamage(Random rand)// 2nd Method to calculate the hero's Damage during battle.
     {
         int attackdamage;
         attackdamage = rand.Next(350, 450);
         return attackdamage;
     }
        int GetMonsterDamage(Random rand) // 3rd Method to calculate the monster's damage during the battle.
         {
         int attackdamage;
         attackdamage = rand.Next(250, 350);
         return attackdamage;
     }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program CH = new Program();
            int heroHitPoints, monsterHitPoints, attackdamage, healing, fleechance, hitchance;
            Random rand;
            string battlechoice;
            Console.WriteLine("You are facing a Monster!");
            //this is outside the loop so that it will only print once
            heroHitPoints = 1500;// our variables are assigned ouside
            monsterHitPoints =2000;//so that each loop won't "heal" them
            do
            {
                rand = new Random();
                CH.DisplayChoices(heroHitPoints, monsterHitPoints);
                battlechoice = Console.ReadLine();
                switch (battlechoice)
                {
                    case "a":
                    case "A"://this way a or A work
                        hitchance = rand.Next(0, 100);
                        if (hitchance > 30)
                        {
                            attackdamage = CH.GetHeroDamage(rand);
                            Console.WriteLine("The hero attacks!");
                            monsterHitPoints -= attackdamage;
                            Console.WriteLine("The monster loses {0}hp", attackdamage);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("You missed!");
                        }
                        break;
                    case "d":
                    case "D":
                        Console.WriteLine("The Hero Defends");
                        break;
                    case "h":
                    case "H":
                        healing = 400;
                        heroHitPoints += healing;
                        Console.WriteLine("The Hero uses a Potion!");
                        Console.WriteLine("The Hero heals himself for {0} Points", healing);
                        break;
                    case "f":
                    case "F":
                        fleechance = rand.Next(0, 100);
                        if (fleechance > 40)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("The hero fled!");
                            Console.ReadLine();
                            Environment.Exit(0);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Fleeing Failed");
                            Console.ReadLine();

                        }
                        break;
                    default://defaults always a good idea with user input
                        Console.WriteLine("Sorry that choice was invalid and the monster took a cheap shot!");
                        break;
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
                if (monsterHitPoints > 0)//if the monster is still alive
                {
                    hitchance = rand.Next(0, 100);
                    if (hitchance > 30)
                    {
                        attackdamage = CH.GetMonsterDamage(rand);
                        Console.WriteLine("The Monster Attacks!");
                        if (battlechoice == "d" || battlechoice == "D")
                        { //this is so that defend has some sort of benefit
                            attackdamage /= 2;
                        }
                        heroHitPoints -= attackdamage;//subtract the damage
                        Console.WriteLine("The Hero loses {0}hp", attackdamage);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Continue");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Clear();//this clears the screen so that we don't have the
                    //last turns info on it.
                }
            }
            while (heroHitPoints > 0 && monsterHitPoints > 0);

            if (heroHitPoints > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You are Victorious!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have been defeated :(");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

     }
```

The program is supposed to ask you to pick a choice, and after you do it performs it, the monster is supposed to attack no matter what. I created 3 methods and called them.
My problem is that the part that starts with an IF statement and ends before the while sometimes runs and sometimes doesn't, like it's completely random, I thought it would be something to do with the monster's hitchance but that wasn't the case, help is appreciated. VS2010 does not give me any errors, and the hero attacks every time even though am using the same way with both of them.

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code, aka debugging it? Maybe with breakpoints, or maybe just with F10/F11

Comment: I did, but it does not show any errors, it runs normally, except that part is random.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but isn't that code _supposed_ to run completely at random, since you've calculated the likelihood with `hitchance = rand.Next(0, 100);`?

Comment: @Tharwen, I think the OP means the other IF, the one with "monsterHitPoints > 0"

Comment: It will run if the monster is alive, but if your slated attack kills it, that code won't run because presumably `monsterHitPoints` is `<= 0`.

Comment: @KingCronus That bit works fine for me...

Comment: yes am sorry all, The IF am talking about is the one that's after the case statement's default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. I've tried it and it works ok, but you don't print anything when the monster misses, is this what you mean by random failure? To rectify it, simply append an `else` to the condition:

```
hitchance = rand.Next(0, 100);
if (hitchance > 30)
{
    attackdamage = CH.GetMonsterDamage(rand);
    Console.WriteLine("The Monster Attacks!");
    if (battlechoice == "d" || battlechoice == "D")
    { //this is so that defend has some sort of benefit
        attackdamage /= 2;
    }
    heroHitPoints -= attackdamage;//subtract the damage
    Console.WriteLine("The Hero loses {0}hp", attackdamage);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("The monster misses!");
}
```

Comment: maybe move the "The Monster Attacks!" outside the `if(hitchance > 30)`, for clarity?

Comment: @Marc True, but this is consistent with the hero attacking :-)

Comment: @Marc I like to think the hero and the monster are Jedi (or at the very least Force sensitive) so they know before they do it whether the attack is going to hit or miss, so on miss they simply act as if they weren't attacking... lol

Answer (score 1):

I think it is working fine; you're just getting unlucky due to `hitchance`. The monster does attack, though, depending on hitchance:

```
You are facing a Monster!

************************************************
Your hero has 1500hp and the Monster has 2000hp
************************************************
__________________________
Please Choose an action:
(A)ttack
(D)efend
(H)eal
(F)lee
__________________________
a
The hero attacks!
The monster loses 442hp

The Monster Attacks!
The Hero loses 348hp
Press Enter to Continue
```

Answer (score 1):

I've refactored your code just for fun :) After extracting some classes `Game`, `Hero`, `Monster` and moving related logic there (yep, OOP), your game looks like:

```
class Program
{     
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Game game = new Game();
        game.Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

All game logic moved to `Game` class, which responsible for creating and managing characters, displaying game to user, and retrieving user input:

```
public class Game
{
    private const int _dispalyWidth = 42;

    public void Start()
    {
        Hero hero = new Hero();
        Monster monster = new Monster();
        Console.WriteLine("You are facing a Monster!");
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.Clear();

        do
        {
            DisplayBattle(hero, monster);

            switch (GetChoice())
            {
                case BattleChoice.Attack:
                    hero.Attack(monster);
                    break;
                case BattleChoice.Defend:
                    hero.Defend();
                    break;
                case BattleChoice.Heal:
                    hero.Heal(400);
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Monster took a cheap shot!");
                    break;
            }                

            if (monster.IsAlive)
                monster.Attack(hero);

            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Continue");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
        }
        while(hero.IsAlive && monster.IsAlive);

        DisplayBattleResult(hero);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private void DisplayBattleResult(Hero hero)
    {
        if (hero.IsAlive)
            Console.WriteLine("You are victorious!");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("You have been defeated :(");
    }

    private void DisplayBattle(Hero hero, Monster monster)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new String('*', _dispalyWidth));
        Console.WriteLine("{0} has {1}hp and the {2} has {3}hp", 
            hero.Name, hero.HitPoints, monster.Name, monster.HitPoints);
        Console.WriteLine(new String('*', _dispalyWidth));
    }

    private void DisplayChoices()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new String('-', _dispalyWidth));
        Console.WriteLine("Please Choose an action:");
        Console.WriteLine("(A)ttack");
        Console.WriteLine("(D)efend");
        Console.WriteLine("(H)eal");
        Console.WriteLine("(F)lee");
        Console.WriteLine(new String('-', _dispalyWidth));
    }

    private BattleChoice GetChoice()
    {
        DisplayChoices();
        ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey(true);
        switch (key.Key)
        {
            case ConsoleKey.A:
                return BattleChoice.Attack;
            case ConsoleKey.H:
                return BattleChoice.Heal;
            case ConsoleKey.D:
                return BattleChoice.Defend;
            default:
                return BattleChoice.Wait;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I introduced classes for hero and monster. They are inherited from `Character` class, which responsible for holding and manipulating character's data:

```
public class Character
{
    private readonly Random _random = new Random();

    public Character(string name, int hitPoints, Range damageRange, int hitChance)
    {
        Name = name;
        HitPoints = hitPoints;
        HitChance = hitChance;
        DamageRange = damageRange;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int HitChance { get; private set; }
    public int HitPoints { get; private set; }
    public Range DamageRange { get; private set; }
    private bool IsDefending { get; set; }

    public bool IsAlive
    {
        get { return HitPoints > 0; }
    }

    public void Defend()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The {0} defends", Name);
        IsDefending = true;
    }

    public void Heal(int amount)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The {0} uses a Potion!", Name);            
        IsDefending = false;
        HitPoints += amount;
        Console.WriteLine("The {0} heals himself for {0} points", amount);
    }

    public void Hit(int amount)
    {
        int receivedDamage = IsDefending ? (amount / 2) : amount;
        HitPoints -= receivedDamage;
        Console.WriteLine("The {0} loses {1}hp", Name, receivedDamage);
    }

    public void Attack(Character target)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The {0} attacks!", Name);
        IsDefending = false;

        if (HitChance <= _random.Next(0, 100))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} missed!", Name);
            return;
        }

        target.Hit(_random.Next(DamageRange.Min, DamageRange.Max));
    }
}

public class Hero : Character
{
    public Hero()
        : base("Hero", 1500, new Range(350, 450), 30)
    {
    }   
}

public class Monster : Character
{
    public Monster()
        : base("Monster", 2000, new Range(250, 350), 30)
    {
    }
}
```

I also used range, for holding possible damages (maybe it's nice to hold damage chance in same object also):

```
public class Range
{
    public Range(int min, int max)
    {
        Min = min;
        Max = max;
    }

    public int Min { get; private set; }
    public int Max { get; private set; }
}
```

And enumeration which describes user's choice:

```
public enum BattleChoice
{
    Attack,
    Defend,
    Heal,
    Wait
}
```

I think it would be nice to move chance verification and damage generation to some class like `Universe`, but it's for you.
Good luck!